# How to overload compound-assignment in c++?

Tags: c++, class, type-conversion, operator-overloading, compound-assignment

point.h

```cpp
...
Point operator +=(double & left, const Point & right) {
    return Point(left + right.x, left + right.y, left + right.z);
}
// std::ostream is overloaded
...
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

int main() {
    double a = 1.0;
    Point b(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    a += b;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

I would like to return the sum:

```
(2, 2, 2)
```

But the double type is preserved by compiler when compound-assignment.

Comment: `a` is a double. There is no way `cout << a << endl;` will ever return `(2, 2, 2)`. Also, `+=` is supposed to modify the LHS operand, not create a new object with a different type.

Comment: what you really want to do is swap operands in your += operator, modify an existing point in it instead of creating a new one, and in your main.cpp use b += a.

Comment: @Danilo Show the class definition.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: You are mixed up. Variables can't change their type in C++; once `a` is a double it is always a double.  Perhaps you meant something like `Point c = a + b;`

Answer (score 2):

This operator definition

```
Point operator +=(double & left, const Point & right) {
    return Point(left + right.x, left + right.y, left + right.z);
}
```

is wrong because it assigns nothing to the left operand and does not return the lvalue of the assigned object.

In general it is better to define such operators as class member functions.

I would define it the following way

```
class Point
{
    //...
    Point & operator +=( const Point &rhs )
    {
        x += rhs.x;
        y += rhs.y;
        z += rhs.z;

        return *this;
    }
    //...
};
```

As for your code and particularly this statement

```
a += b;
```

then it is not clear whether there is a conversion constructor that converts an object of type double (the type that object a has) to type Point because you did not show the class definition. And as I already pointed out the operator you defined does not change the left operand (a temporary object of type Point that would be created based on the object `a`). So if even the record above is correct in any case the original object `a` will not be changed.

For an objects of type double used as the left operand  you could define operator + instead of the operator +=.

For example

```
const Point operator +( double lhs, const Point &rhs )
{
    Point p( rhs.x + lhs, rhs.y + lhs, rhs.z + lhs );

    return p;
}
```

The details of the implementation for your class can be different because I do not see the class definition. Nevertheless this definition demonstrates the idea.

In this case you could write

```
double a = 1.0;
Point b( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );

std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
```

and get the expected result

```
(2, 2, 2)
```